# Parse JSON forecast data from Wunderground

Tags: c#, json, parsing, wunderground

I am querying Wunderground service for a 10 day forecast and I need to parse the data. The approach by using class creator like [Json2Sharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and then accessing the RootObject works but is not preferable. What I need is a simple token parse, however, I do not understand how to approach complex JSON structure. For instance, how can I extract Weekday and Temperature from a nested response like this (using C#):

```
{
  "response": {
  "version": "0.1",
  "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "forecast10day": 1
  }
  },
  "forecast": {
  "txt_forecast": {
  "date": "8:00 AM PDT",
  "forecastday": [{
  "period": 0,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Tuesday",
  "fcttext": "Overcast in the morning, then clear. High of 75F. Winds from the SSW at 5 to 20 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Overcast in the morning, then clear. High of 24C. Windy. Winds from the SSW at 5 to 30 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 1,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Tuesday Night",
  "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy. Low of 55F. Winds from the SW at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy. Low of 13C. Breezy. Winds from the SW at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 2,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Wednesday",
  "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 72F. Winds from the SW at 10 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 22C. Breezy. Winds from the SW at 15 to 25 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 3,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Wednesday Night",
  "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the SW at 10 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Breezy. Winds from the SW at 15 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 4,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Thursday",
  "fcttext": "Mostly cloudy. Fog early. High of 70F. Winds from the WSW at 10 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Mostly cloudy. Fog early. High of 21C. Windy. Winds from the WSW at 15 to 25 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 5,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Thursday Night",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the WNW at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 6,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Friday",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 72F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy in the morning, then clear. High of 22C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 7,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Friday Night",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the WNW at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the WNW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 8,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Saturday",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog early. High of 73F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog early. High of 23C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 9,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Saturday Night",
  "fcttext": "Clear. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the West at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 10,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Sunday",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. High of 72F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. High of 22C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 11,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Sunday Night",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the West at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 12,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Monday",
  "fcttext": "Clear. High of 70F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. High of 21C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 13,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Monday Night",
  "fcttext": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 55F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Partly cloudy. Fog overnight. Low of 13C. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 14,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Tuesday",
  "fcttext": "Clear. High of 75F. Winds from the West at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. High of 24C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 15,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Tuesday Night",
  "fcttext": "Clear. Low of 59F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. Low of 15C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 16,
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "title": "Wednesday",
  "fcttext": "Clear. High of 73F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. High of 23C. Winds from the West at 5 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 17,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Wednesday Night",
  "fcttext": "Clear. Low of 59F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. Low of 15C. Breezy. Winds from the West at 10 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 18,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Thursday",
  "fcttext": "Clear. High of 73F. Winds from the West at 5 to 15 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. High of 23C. Winds from the West at 5 to 20 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }, {
  "period": 19,
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "title": "Thursday Night",
  "fcttext": "Clear. Low of 57F. Winds from the WSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
  "fcttext_metric": "Clear. Low of 14C. Winds from the WSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
  "pop": "0"
  }]
  },
  "simpleforecast": {
  "forecastday": [{
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341381600",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 03, 2012",
  "day": 3,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 184,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Tue",
  "weekday": "Tuesday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 1,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "75",
  "celsius": "24"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 17,
  "kph": 27,
  "dir": "WSW",
  "degrees": 255
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 14,
  "kph": 22,
  "dir": "WSW",
  "degrees": 241
  },
  "avehumidity": 72,
  "maxhumidity": 82,
  "minhumidity": 62
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341468000",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 04, 2012",
  "day": 4,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 185,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Wed",
  "weekday": "Wednesday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 2,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "72",
  "celsius": "22"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "partlycloudy",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 15,
  "kph": 24,
  "dir": "WSW",
  "degrees": 237
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 12,
  "kph": 19,
  "dir": "SW",
  "degrees": 231
  },
  "avehumidity": 79,
  "maxhumidity": 89,
  "minhumidity": 54
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341554400",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 05, 2012",
  "day": 5,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 186,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Thu",
  "weekday": "Thursday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 3,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "70",
  "celsius": "21"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 15,
  "kph": 24,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 265
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 13,
  "kph": 21,
  "dir": "WSW",
  "degrees": 250
  },
  "avehumidity": 77,
  "maxhumidity": 87,
  "minhumidity": 64
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341640800",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 06, 2012",
  "day": 6,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 187,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Fri",
  "weekday": "Friday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 4,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "72",
  "celsius": "22"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "sunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 272
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 9,
  "kph": 14,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 274
  },
  "avehumidity": 70,
  "maxhumidity": 84,
  "minhumidity": 58
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341727200",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 07, 2012",
  "day": 7,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 188,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Sat",
  "weekday": "Saturday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 5,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "73",
  "celsius": "23"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Fog",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 266
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 9,
  "kph": 14,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 270
  },
  "avehumidity": 75,
  "maxhumidity": 85,
  "minhumidity": 61
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341813600",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 08, 2012",
  "day": 8,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 189,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Sun",
  "weekday": "Sunday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 6,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "72",
  "celsius": "22"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Fog",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "partlycloudy",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 265
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 9,
  "kph": 14,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 266
  },
  "avehumidity": 79,
  "maxhumidity": 88,
  "minhumidity": 66
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341900000",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 09, 2012",
  "day": 9,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 190,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Mon",
  "weekday": "Monday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 7,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "70",
  "celsius": "21"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "55",
  "celsius": "13"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 10,
  "kph": 16,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 263
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 9,
  "kph": 14,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 269
  },
  "avehumidity": 85,
  "maxhumidity": 92,
  "minhumidity": 67
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1341986400",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 10, 2012",
  "day": 10,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 191,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Tue",
  "weekday": "Tuesday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 8,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "75",
  "celsius": "24"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "59",
  "celsius": "15"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "sunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 10,
  "kph": 16,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 264
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 8,
  "kph": 13,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 263
  },
  "avehumidity": 78,
  "maxhumidity": 90,
  "minhumidity": 58
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1342072800",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 11, 2012",
  "day": 11,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 192,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Wed",
  "weekday": "Wednesday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 9,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "73",
  "celsius": "23"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "59",
  "celsius": "15"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "mostlysunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 273
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 8,
  "kph": 13,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 268
  },
  "avehumidity": 76,
  "maxhumidity": 93,
  "minhumidity": 58
  }, {
  "date": {
  "epoch": "1342159200",
  "pretty": "11:00 PM PDT on July 12, 2012",
  "day": 12,
  "month": 7,
  "year": 2012,
  "yday": 193,
  "hour": 23,
  "min": "00",
  "sec": 0,
  "isdst": "1",
  "monthname": "July",
  "weekday_short": "Thu",
  "weekday": "Thursday",
  "ampm": "PM",
  "tz_short": "PDT",
  "tz_long": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  "period": 10,
  "high": {
  "fahrenheit": "73",
  "celsius": "23"
  },
  "low": {
  "fahrenheit": "57",
  "celsius": "14"
  },
  "conditions": "Clear",
  "icon": "clear",
  "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
  "skyicon": "sunny",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
  "in": 0.00,
  "mm": 0.0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
  "in": 0,
  "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
  "mph": 11,
  "kph": 18,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 268
  },
  "avewind": {
  "mph": 8,
  "kph": 13,
  "dir": "West",
  "degrees": 263
  },
  "avehumidity": 71,
  "maxhumidity": 89,
  "minhumidity": 53
  }]
  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this tool](http://json.parser.online.fr/) I was able to get a good visual on the structure of this response. The answer was quiet simple, to get first day's forecast temperature in Celsius is simply:

```
string tempCelsius = (string)jsonObject.SelectToken("forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.celsius");
```

Using a good tool for visualizing JSON structure was the key.

Answer (score 3):

Your first task is to choose a JSON serializer.  My preference is [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), but there's also [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and various others.  Your mileage may vary.

The next task is to create a C# class that matches the output.  Once that is done, you can then de serialize with ease.

In ServiceStack, it's a simple case of:

```
string json = @"<what you have above>";
MyPoco = json.FromJson<MyPoco>(json);
```

Comment: The problem is as stated that I cannot serialize into Objects. I need a solution of type (string)jsonObject.SelectToken("current_observation.weather") as in simple observation response.

Comment: @eYe, why can't you serialize in to objects?

Comment: it is a specific requirement in order to avoid having to regenerate a lot of code upon API changes :(

Comment: @eYe, your requirement to go to a specific token through a tree will break the moment an API changes also.  Either way, it's easier this way.  If the API changes, *a change has to be made somewhere*.  It's easy if you're dealing with C# objects and not some arbitrary tree that will break also.

Comment: I totally agree but it is just a spec that needs to be fullilled.